# Use different column as default value in waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In my sails application I have a model that has the attributes `cjdnsIp` and `adminIp`. Now I want the `adminIp` field to be the same as `cjdnsIp` if no other value is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model override `beforeValidate: fn(values, cb)` function and set `adminIp = cjdnsIp`  if it's not set.

Look the documentation : http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html